# Samba error message invoke-rc.d: initscript samba, action "restart" failed

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

Hello I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 Newbies

I try to create a samba share.

it is installed, and I think it is running, I create users and a shared folder on a secondary internal hard drive sata automatically mounted at startup.

the trouble is that as soon as I created my shared folder with the "system-comfig-samba" command when clicked on create this error in the terminal

"invoke-rc.d: initscript samba, action," restart "failed." it appears has all my manipulations in the samba configuration manager cited above

and if I go to my pc running Ubuntu from Windows I see my folder but I can not access it. win7 diagnostics wonder my internet connection. but I go to another shared samba folder by default. if it is shared by samba.

I can give more info if you told me how to proceed.

thank you for your help ...

Michael

Answer (score -1):

You can restart samba manually by.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd restart
```

You may need need to restart windows too or wait for some time clicking refresh to purge windows cache. You may have problem to connect to one samba server with 2 different users.

BTW: samba will always give you problems cause its m$oft. (cannot change ip ports, it not encrypted, so good for local net only) Use ssh if you can. If you just need to copy files winscp.net will do the job.

BTW2: ubuntu (or system-config-samba) guys could handle to restart samba processes cause it's been years already (in 14.10 the problem still persist and I remember it was there before 13.?)